# React Query SSR prefetchQuery not firing request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql, react-query

I'm trying to fetch some data from SpaceX's GraphQL API. I'm using Next, React Query, and GraphQL Code Generator.

Once everything is generated the SSR implementation using `queryClient.prefetchQuery` doesn't work as I would expect as the HTML document is always blank. Side note by using not using code generation prefetching works as expected.

This was my abbreviated working example:

```
index.tsx

..
import { useQuery, QueryClient, dehydrate } from "react-query"
import { gql, request } from 'graphql-request'

const API_URL = "https://api.spacex.land/graphql/";

const getLaunchesPast = async () => {
  const data = await request(
    API_URL, 
    gql`...query...`
  );
  return data;
};

const Home: NextPage = (props) => {
  const { data } = useQuery("launchesPast", getLaunchesPast);
  return (...);
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery('launchesPast', getLaunchesPast);
  
  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient)
    }
  }
}
export default Home
```

Using this approach I was able to see the HTML document initially render with data. However, when trying to use Code Generation and wiring it up I'm no longer able to prefetch server-side and only fetch client-side

---

```
launchesPast.gql

query getLaunchesPast($limit: Int) {
    launchesPast(limit: $limit) {
      mission_name
      launch_date_local
    }
  }
```

```
condegen.yml

overwrite: true
schema: "https://api.spacex.land/graphql/"
documents: "./src/graphql/**/*.gql"
generates:
  src/generated.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-query
    config:
      pureMagicComment: true
      exposeQueryKeys: true
      fetcher: graphql-request
        endpoint: "https://api.spacex.land/graphql/"
        fetchParams:
          headers:
            Content-Type: "application/json"
      exposeFetcher: true
```

```
_app.tsx

import { useState } from 'react'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { Hydrate, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query'
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient());

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp
```

```
index.tsx

import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { QueryClient, dehydrate} from "react-query"[![enter image description here][1]][1]

import { GetLaunchesPastQuery, useGetLaunchesPastQuery } from '../generated';

const Home: NextPage = (props) => {
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetLaunchesPastQuery<GetLaunchesPastQuery>({ limit: 5 });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        {data?.launchesPast && (
          <ul>
            {data?.launchesPast.map((launch) => (
              <li key={launch?.mission_name}>{launch?.mission_name} ({launch?.launch_date_local})</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  await queryClient.prefetchQuery(useGetLaunchesPastQuery.getKey(), () =>
    useGetLaunchesPastQuery.fetcher({ limit: 10 })
  );

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dehydrate(queryClient))),
    },
  };
};

export default Home
```

[image: client side seeing data server side data is an empty object]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue with my own GraphQL endpoint and the custom hooks which @graphql-codegen generates for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue there is not much information on usage, When you useinfiniteQuery you need to use `prefetchInfiniteQuery` instead `prefetchQuery` in the server

Example:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  query,
  req,
}) => {

  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  const result = await queryClient.prefetchInfiniteQuery(
    {
      queryKey: useInfiniteGetProductsStoreFrontQuery.getKey({ limit: 3 }),
        // Take care use the method without the prefix Infinite and then in the client side the keys need to match 
      queryFn: useGetProductsStoreFrontQuery.fetcher(client, {
        limit: 3,
      }),
    }


return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dehydrate(queryClient))),
     },
  };
```

Client side

```
const { data, fetchNextPage } = useInfiniteGetProductsStoreFrontQuery(
    "page",
    client,
    {
      limit: 3
    },
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {

        if (lastPage.searchProductsStoreFront.length > 0) {
          return {
            page: pages.length + 1,
          };
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

With this example you will have the data already cached